# Azure IoT - SAS generation considerations

Tags: azure, iot

I would like to implement a multi-tenant environment with IoT hub where I want to allow each tenant to connect directly to IoT hub (as service) to communicate with devices. Of course I would want each tenant to have access only to their own devices and not have the possibility to connect to devices from other tenants (thus I require the proper SAS).

Following the documentation on the ServiceConnect permissions, it would seem that it is not possible to do this restriction on a SAS level. I am expecting an URL like "{host}/devices/{device_id}/...." (where .... is devicebound or messages or something), but did not find a sample and the piece of code that I came up with result in Unauthorized.

I would like to know what strategies can I use to allow this multi-tenant connection to IoT hub. Did anyone manage to create a SAS with ServiceConnect to device specific URL? Is it even possible or what other workarounds are there for this scenario?

Also, if you have any samples with generating a SAS that allows me to use the endpoint {host}/messages/devicebound, I would appreciate it a lot.

Thanks,
George

Comment: I do not *think* this was possible. Someone able to get data from devices can get it from any device. Devices can have the device-specific keys and all that but the same doesn't apply to services listening for data. One obvious option would be to create an IoT Hub per tenant :)

Comment: It is indeed an option, but not cost effective and not so much automated. The maintenance is pretty complicated to support hub-per-tenant when you have hundredths of tenants.

Comment: Which documentation of ServiceConnect permissions did you follow? And do you mind showing your code of "result in Unauthorized"?